# Powershell two dotas after slash meaning

Tags: powershell

Starting with Powershell and found this command `Set-Location -Path .\..`

What does `.\..` supposed to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, paths are separated by backslashes `\` by default (though some applications and APIs will accept forward slashes `/`). As in Unix/Linux, `.` represents the current directory, and `..` represents the parent directory of the current directory. The expression `.\..` thus represents 'the parent directory relative to the current directory'.